# cakephp routing without id?

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there any way to route urls in cake without having the ID in the url?

So instead of www.mydomain.com/id/article-name I just want www.mydomain.com/article-name

I've been following this.
http://book.cakephp.org/view/543/Passing-parameters-to-action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. The only requirement for this is that there's enough unique information in the URL to pin down the article you want. If `/article-name` is unique in your database, you can use it to find the specific record you want.

In config/routes.php:

```
// ... configure all normal routes first ...

Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view'));
```

In controllers/articles_controller.php:

```
function view ($article_name) {
    $article = $this->Article->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Article.name' => $article_name)
    ));
    ...
}
```

Be careful not to name your products like anything that could legitimately appear in the URL, so you don't run into conflicts. Does the URL `http://example.com/pages` point to the product 'pages' or to `array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index')`? For this purpose you'll also need to define your routes in `routes.php` in a way that allows all your controllers to be accessible first, and only the undefined rest gets piped into your `ArticlesController`. Look at the [third parameter of `Routes::connect`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/542/Defining-Routes), which allows you to specify a RegEx filter you could use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
// In routes.php
$rewrites = array();
$rewrites = am($rewrites, ClassRegistry::init('Article')->rewrites());
$rewrites = am($rewrites, ClassRegistry::init('AnotherModel')->rewrites());
$rewrites = am($rewrites, ClassRegistry::init('YetAnother')->rewrites());
foreach ($rewrites as $rewrite) {
    Router::connect($rewrite[0], $rewrite[1], $rewrite[2]);
}
```

With deceze's method, you can only have one catch all. In this method, you can define a whole stack if you want.

This method is kind of hacky though, since you are querying the model from a config file.